# Populating a layout using a table from OBDC

Tags: filemaker

I have been able to set up OBDC in Filemaker, and added `table`, a MySQL table, in Filemaker's relationship diagram.

I want to set up a layout, to view the entire contents of `table`, at the moment it displays a much smaller number of records than there should be, initially only 3 Total (where it should be 150).

However, if I go to Find Mode, and type in the `id` of one of the records which is not displayed, it is subsequently appended to the table (so I now have 4 "Total" records).

How can I display the *entire* contents of this table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't state what OS you're on nor what your ODBC driver is, but assuming it's a Mac with the Actual Technologies driver, it sounds like the driver isn't registered.

From http://www.actualtech.com/product_opensourcedatabases.php

> Downloaded driver has all features turned on, except that it will only return 3 rows from any query until the driver is registered

Answer (score 1):

pft221 is correct on the recordset result, but you will often find that you will need to perform the script step "Refresh Window" with [Flush cached SQL data] checked periodically to refresh rows of data if the datasource is actively being updated.